# How to update table when rows of one table are different from the other

Tags: sql-server

I have a table table1 and a temporary table temp2. Temp2 contains updated values which i want to update in table1. So, for any rows that are different i want to update the values from Temp2 to table 1. I tried something like this but its not working.

```
update Role_Master set Role_Desc=Role_Descc , Role_Version_Number =Role_Version_Number+1,Role_Dept=Role_Deptt,Role_All_Clients=Role_All_Clientss,
            Role_Admin=Role_Adminn,Role_Super_Admin=Role_Super_Adminn,Role_Modified_Date = GETDATE(),Role_Modified_By = 'T6086' FROM  #TEMP1 where Role_ID in
            (SELECT #TEMP1.Role_IDD FROM #TEMP1  LEFT JOIN Role_Master ON (#TEMP1.Role_Descc = Role_Master.Role_Desc and #Temp1.Role_Deptt=Role_Master.Role_Dept)
            WHERE Role_Master.Role_Desc is null and Role_Master.Role_Dept IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

hard to help you without knowing the schema of the two tables ... but it should be possible to join the two tables and decide by a where condition which rows to update ... check out this simple example ... maybe it helps

```
create table #temp1 (id int, val nvarchar(100))
create table #temp2 (id int, val nvarchar(100))

insert into #temp1 (id, val) values (1, 'eins')
insert into #temp1 (id, val) values (2, 'eins')
insert into #temp1 (id, val) values (3, 'eins')

insert into #temp2 (id, val) values (1, 'zwei')
insert into #temp2 (id, val) values (2, 'eins')
insert into #temp2 (id, val) values (3, 'eins')

update #temp1 set #temp1.val = b.val
    from #temp1 a join #temp2 b on a.id = b.id
    where a.val <> b.val

select @@rowcount           -- returns 1 because 1 row was updated
select * from #temp1
```